# $.each iterating through returned json from jquery fails in firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, each

In chrome and safari, the following code works fine.

in `firefox`, all platforms, all versions, it does not work and throws an error that object is undefined (from jQuery) stopping on the `$.each` loop

This code calls a json web service via AJAX and returns JSON.

ideas?

***CODE***

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "URL GOES HERE",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "geoNear": "geotestnew",
        "near": [-73.78086565, 41.014072],
        "maxDistance": 0.3
    }),
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) {
        var usthis = data.results;
        $.each(usthis, function(entryIndex, entry) {
            var newdis = this.dis * 69;
            $("#results").append('<br>');
            $("#results").append(newdis);
            $("#results").append('<br>');
            $("#results").append(this.obj.Name);
            $("#results").append('<br>');
        });
    },
    error: function(x, e) {
        $('body').html('error: ' + e);
    }
});
});​
```

Comment: Formatted code is much easier to read! What is the value of `data` in the callback?

Comment: Can you use a tool like Firebug to record the JSON that's coming back from the service (the response should appear on the console tab). Perhaps with that we (or you) could tell what's going wrong.

Comment: If your problem is browser specific, I'd start by inspecting the contents of `data` when its returned from the server; sounds like Firefox does not see a `data.results` object

Comment: in firefox, it is seeing the correct and complete JSON ...  here is a sample response (from mongo db )  see this url: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set `dataType` in ajax options to let jQuery know what type of response to expect

```
   dataType:'json' // or 'jsonp' which it appears you may be using
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: yes!!!  that's it ...  the dataTYpe needed to set to json  (not json p...  I guess chrome and safari dont need it.. and if it's blank the docs said it will "guess" .. which I must fail on firefox

Comment: been there...done that! ...frustrating when you can see the data too. Jquery does a best guess, but not always on the mark, depending on browser

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple things wrong here:

1. you dont have a dataType set.  the Format of the returned data is
   determined by the dataType property.
2. you have crossDomain set to true, but are using contentType of "json" rather than "jsonp" which is needed for cross domain requests.
3. when using json, as the datatype, I have always used `data.d` in the success method rather than `data.results`

Here's code i have used for local json ajax request:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Svcs.asmx/GetStateProvOptions",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{ 'countryID': '" + countryID + "' }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            var result = data.d;
            var options = [];
            options.push('<option value="0" selected="selected">All</option>');
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                options.push('<option value="', result[i].ID, '">', result[i].Value, '</option>');
            }
            $('.ddl').html(options.join(''));
        },
        error: Ajax_Error
    });
```

also check out the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) docs for more info there..

And here's an explanation about the `data.d`:
http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/

Comment: the object properties depend on structure of the return. If the data looks like `{"results":[.....]}` then you have to use `data.results`